# Play youtube video embed in the app

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

Anyone know how to play the youtube videos embed in the app to avoid the video play in the ios native player out of the app as is the commom behaivor ?

I usint a component variable to load the video with  youtube/embed/videoid

thx.

Comment: Did you try using the Video domain and assigning the YouTube URL? Haw are you loading the video in the Component variable?

Comment: Hi Marcos this is exactly what I do, I using a Att that is a Video Domain and fill this att with the youtube url like youtube/embed/videoid its works fine and the video is played fine but the video is played in the iOS native player and not inside the app or embed in the app.

Comment: What does the URL looks like? It should be something like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=...

Comment: Hi Marcos, once I use the embed in the url the component load the video like embed see this :   https://www.youtube.com/embed/EkUFA1U9j1Y?rel=0&fs=0  but when i tap to play the iOS play the video in the native ios player out of the app not inside the app, you got ?

Answer (score 0):

I just did a sample app that plays a YouTube video and it is working as expected, the movie gets played without leaving the application.

If you have the Knowledge Base Navigator you can try the sample app here: http://apps2.genexusx.com/Id40bcbd2af97907aa1658220df3b715ce

The particular video you mention in the comments says it has copyrighted material and cannot be played outside the YouTube app. Maybe that's the problem.

Another thing to consider is the YouTube link format, it should be something like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6-tWvSZIWw (by the way, that was the one I used).

Comment: Hi Marcos, I access your test via KBN and I got the same behaivor of my app, in advanced I talk about the iOS because in the Android its work fine, but in iOS the video keeping Loading video... when use /watch?v=VideoID but if use the embed/videoid the video play fine....    you try your test in the KBN in iOS ?   thx

Comment: Yes, iOS 8.2 on an iPhone... I don't know what it may be, then.

Comment: Me too, iOS 8.2 iPhone 6 Plus :-(   I access your test from KBN ev3 and its the same the video keeps Loading....    can you please add the url in this format ->   https://www.youtube.com/embed/D6-tWvSZIWw     for we test ?